# Moving a div to a different parent, which also moves, using matchMedia

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm very new to JavaScript so I thought I'd ask for someone to have a quick look over this to make sure it isn't brittle, buggy, or completely unnecessary. It may be all three. I also thought it might help someone in the future (if correct), as I found lots of different suggestions I don't think I needed including looping through all the child nodes and using enquire.js.

It moves a div from one parent container to another depending on whether a media query is relevant. The target div also moves with a normal css media query.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VdbKdE?editors=1111) (make the container height a fair bit taller than the width)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container container1" id="c1">
    <div class="item item1">1</div>
    <div class="item item2" id="toMove">2</div>
    <div class="item item3" id="item3">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container container2" id="c2">
    <div class="item item4">4</div>
    <!-- Item3 will end up here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eaeaea;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 4/5){
  .wrapper{
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container1{
  flex-basis: 66.6%;
  background: red;
}

.container2{
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
  background: blue;
}

.item{
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

js

```
var container1 = document.getElementById('c1');
var container2 = document.getElementById('c2');
var item = document.getElementById('toMove');

matchMedia("screen and (min-aspect-ratio:4/5)").addListener(function(mql) {
   if(mql.matches) {
       moveElement(item, container1);
   }
   else {
       moveElement(item, container2);
   }
});

function moveElement(source, target){
    target.appendChild(source);
}
```

Appreciate the feedback as I don't really know what I'm doing with JS!

*fixed the problem in the example RE moving the item back to its original location. I just call the method `container1.insertBefore(toMove, item3);` in the 'else' block, instead of calling moveElement(). (where item3 is a variable pointing to #item3)

In case that helps anyone.